# Error during "make all" in Caffe

Tags: protocol-buffers, caffe

I had an error after running the `make all` command while compiling Caffe. Here is what I got (it is a snippet):

```
CXX .build_release/src/caffe/proto/caffe.pb.cc
AR -o .build_release/lib/libcaffe.a
LD -o .build_release/lib/libcaffe.so
CXX/LD -o .build_release/tools/upgrade_net_proto_text.bin
CXX/LD -o .build_release/tools/caffe.bin
.build_release/lib/libcaffe.so: undefined reference to `google::protobuf::io::CodedInputStream::~CodedInputStream()'
.build_release/lib/libcaffe.so: undefined reference to `google::protobuf::io::CodedInputStream::default_recursion_limit_'
.build_release/lib/libcaffe.so: undefined reference to `google::protobuf::io::CodedInputStream::BytesUntilLimit() const'
.build_release/lib/libcaffe.so: undefined reference to `google::protobuf::GoogleOnceInitImpl(int*, google::protobuf::Closure*)'
collect2: ld devolvió el estado de salida 1
make: *** [.build_release/tools/upgrade_net_proto_text.bin] Error 1
make: *** Se espera a que terminen otras tareas....
.build_release/lib/libcaffe.so: undefined reference to `google::protobuf::io::CodedInputStream::~CodedInputStream()'
.build_release/lib/libcaffe.so: undefined reference to `google::protobuf::io::CodedInputStream::default_recursion_limit_'
.build_release/lib/libcaffe.so: undefined reference to `google::protobuf::io::CodedInputStream::BytesUntilLimit() const'
.build_release/lib/libcaffe.so: undefined reference to `google::protobuf::GoogleOnceInitImpl(int*, google::protobuf::Closure*)'
collect2: ld devolvió el estado de salida 1
make: *** [.build_release/tools/caffe.bin] Error 1
```

How can I fix this issue?

EDIT: I'm installing it in Ubuntu 12.04.

Answer (score 0):

comment out line 113 in

```
/usr/local/cuda/include/host_config.h.
```

it is because gcc 5 error